# Using wildcard replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

stat  x, y, z,

x/y/z are numbers. Is there any regex command in notepad++ that allows me to replace all the text in a file that matches the pattern (stat  x, y, z,(keep in mind that the numbers that represent x/y/z vary)) in a manner that it reduces x by 2, y and z by 1?

Comment: [He'res a list of all N++ Regex](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do operations against the capture groups inline with the built in regex engine. What you can do is be very clever and have use a regex to automatically write you a script that will do the work you want, then run the script and then save the output of that script.

Regex to capture the numbers:

```
^stat ?([0-9]+), ?([0-9]+), ? ([0-9]+)$
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` start of a line
- "stat" string literal
- `?` optional space
- `([0-9]+)` greedy match of any number sequence, 1 or more characters.
- `,` comma literal
- `?` optional space
- `([0-9]+)` greedy match of any number sequence, 1 or more characters.
- `,` comma literal
- `?` optional space
- `([0-9]+)` greedy match of any number sequence, 1 or
  more characters.
- `$` end of line

You can drop that in your find field, marking to search as a regex search. Then in the "Replace With" field, you can drop the following expression:

`@set /a sa=\1-2\n@set /a sb=\2-1\n@set /a sc=\2-1\necho stat %sa%, %sb%, %sc%\n`

You can then hit replace-all and save the newly generated text into a batch file and run it, which will print out your modified values. This won't take you 100% of the way to a fully automated mechanism. You'd need to have an extra variable that you append each new line to, then print it out only once to get clean output you can straight pipe to a file. But this gets you 99% of the way there.